# From randomly to not randomly selecting columns

Tags: r, random

I have this piece of script for R and I want to adjust it a little bit.

Here's the script I have, `mydata` is an imported `.csv` file of `n` columns:

```
library(orddom)
R=6
delta = numeric (R)
for (i in 1:R) {`
a <- data.matrix(sample(mydata, 2, replace=FALSE)) 
drops <- c(colnames(a)) 
b <- data.matrix(mydata[,!(names(mydata) %in% drops)]) 
a1 <- na.omit(t(matrix(a,1)))
b1 <- na.omit(t(matrix(b,1)))
colnames(a1) <- c("Group 1")
colnames(b1) <- c("Group 2")
delta [i] <- abs(as.numeric(orddom(a1, b1, alpha = 0.05, paired=FALSE)[13,1]))
```

The problem is that for vector a, the columns of mydata get resampled randomly, leading to several equal delta values, because every time the iterative process start again there is a possibility that the same set of columns get selected.

Now I want the columns to be not randomly resampled. So I want all the possible column combinations, column 1 and 2 and 3 is the same combination as column 2 and 1 and 3 and so on, avoiding combinations of one column with itself, without repetition.

Is there a way to exclude column combinations that have already been selected before?

Then I would like to calculate delta for every combination and store it in a vector.

[orddom: Ordinal Dominance Statistics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/orddom/index.html)

Comment: What is function `orddom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
 #get the combos outside the loop
 combos<-combn(length(mydata),2)
 R<-ncol(combos)
 delta<-numeric(R)
 #in the loop, replace the first line
 a <- mydata[,combos[,i]]
 #the rest should be ok
```

There are some improvements you could make in the code but they are not relevant in what you are asking.

Comment: I just tried it, but is gives an error:    `Error in if (s2dw < ((1 - dw^2)/((n_x * n_y) - 1))) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: It is working now. Thanks! I just added 'data.matrix' in front of vector a, so now it is `a <- data.matrix(mydata[,combos[,i]])`